# How to join tables using Hibernate Criteria Query

Tags: database, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a School table and Classroom table which has foreign key to School table. I want to get classrooms that capaties are 40 and school name is "example". Here is my generic getAll method. I want to modify this method to join 2 tables. The problem is the method still must remains generic.

```
public <T> List<T> getAll(T genericEntity) {
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(genericEntity.getClass());
    criteria.add(Example.create(genericEntity));
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Comment: Remain generic?, you want a genetic function for n joins or specifically 2 joins?, what about the parameters?, are you trying to make some kind of super dao for everything?

Answer (score 1):

You should add both objects to the parameter list:

```
public <T,U> List<T> getAll(T genericEntity1, U genericEntity2) {
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(genericEntity1.getClass()).add(Example.create(genericEntity1))
        .createCriteria(genericEntity2.getClass()).add(Example.create(genericEntity2));
    return criteria.list();
}
```

You can call it the following way:

```
getAll(classroom, school);
```